# Why is Firestore storing amounts as strings instead of numbers?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a form which a user can fill out. One of the fields is for an amount which I specified the type to be a "number".

The form is then stored as a document in firestore which saves the amount as a string instead of a number. I have tried different methods without success.

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

thanks

**HTML**

```
      <form id="create-form">

        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="number" step="0.01" id="amount" required>
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        </div>
....
```

**JS**

```
....
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('items').doc('manual').collection('transactions').add({
      amount: createForm.amount.Value,
      name: createForm.name.value,
      category: createForm.category.value,
      date: createForm.date.value,
      userUID: user.uid
    })
....
```

Comment: Did you try with `amount: parseInt(createForm.amount.Value, 10)` ?

Answer (score 4):

When you enter data into a text input field in HTML, its value becomes a string in JavaScript code (since a text field allows input of all types of values).

If you want it to become a numeric value, you need to parse that string into a number:

```
parseInt(createForm.amount.Value)
```

Or if the user is allowed to enter non-whole numbers

```
parseFloat(createForm.amount.Value)
```

If you do that before passing the value to Firestore, it will store the numeric value instead of the string:

```
amount: parseFloat(createForm.amount.Value),
```

---

I had to look this up: the `type="number"` mostly determines what keyboard mobile users will see to enter a value, and may affect the client-side validation of the field's value. But if you access the value in JavaScript, it will still be a string, and thus require the conversion I mentioned above.

Comment: This solves half of the problem because now the data type is stored as a number  in firestore (which is great!) but the amount is NaN

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger? What is the exact value of `createForm.amount.Value`? What is the output of `parseFloat(createForm.amount.Value)`?